# Check for database change with SSE

Tags: php, server-sent-events

Trying to create a small notification system. When user fills out the profile then his verification status is set to 1 in database and then I would like to show a notification once that "hey you are now verified". Been searching a lot on the internet, but nothing has helped me to reach my goal. If the status is 1 in database I get the Event: verification_ok in the `test.php` but if it is 0 I get `Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded`. Also I don't see any response in my client side code.

This is the server side code (test.php).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Connection: Keep-alive");
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHP/scripts/no_session_redirect.php';
$key = true;

$ver = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT verification_status FROM verification WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$ver->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$status = $ver->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($key){
        if($status["verification_status"] == 1){
          pushNotification($status["verification_status"]);
           $key = false;
         }else{
           $status["verification_status"];

        sleep(10);

      }
    }


function pushNotification() {
  echo "Event: verification_ok\n";
}
```

And here is the client side code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
            // Yes! Server-sent events support!
            var source = new EventSource("test.php");
            source.addEventListener("verification_ok", function(e) {
                console.log(e.data);
            }, false);

            source.addEventListener("open", function(e) {

            }, false);

            source.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
                if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                    console.log("Error - connection was lost.");
                }
            }, false);
        } else {
            // Sorry! No server-sent events support..
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this for a one-off notification? You will send the verification success/failure message once, and then never need to send anything down the SSE connection again?  (If it is to be kept open, because other messages will be sent, it might be worth giving some examples of them, just so the answers people give can be more useful.)